# Is it possible to create a Cortana skill that is available only within a single enterprise?

Tags: cortana-skills-kit

Is it possible to create a Cortana skill that is limited to users on a particular company's network?

For example, I would be interested in building a Cortana skill for the [Harman Kardon Invoke](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Cortana-Skills-Kit-Blog/Getting-Started-Build-a-Cortana-Skill-that-can-stream-audio-on/ba-p/121523) smart speaker, but this skill would not be published globally.

Are all skills always published globally or is there a way to control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this isn't possible as a built in functionality for Cortana. There are some ways to deploy to only certain email addresses however. You can use the "deploy to group" functionality outlined here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/publish-skill

Alternatively, you can publish the skill "to world" and force users to authenticate the first time they access the skill, thus limiting it to people with your approved credentials.